# Using `printf` and string format on a single line

Tags: c++

I have problem with using `printf` -- the output doesn't show on a single line.
I do not want to include the library for the `cout` function.

Here my code for printing the data:

```
std::string data;
data = "john";
printf("%s is at home",data.c_str());
```

The output is as follows:

```
john
 is at home
```

How can I make all the text appear on a single line?

Comment: There must be something else wrong with your code. When I compile and run the above code, I get the expected output.

Comment: I get the result on the same line, I just copy pasted the code which you have posted. It works fine. Can you post the function where this is happening.

Comment: I would guess that you're not being truthful about what your code is and that you're actually getting the string from `stdin` with a trailing newline.

Comment: yup i just found the problem is the string that i pass to my function have extra charater of /n. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't happen for me. This [codepad](http://codepad.org/5bmOAaoP) is using the code you provided.

Comment: i try complie on my ubuntu, the terminal print output on a seprate line.

Comment: @letian - works as expected on my Arch Linux box. gcc 4.7.2. For completeness, also works with clang version 3.2

Comment: ok i go check my code again. maybe my data string have included the /n